# After joining computer to Active Directory domain, network connection keeps dropping

Tags: windows-10, networking, remote-desktop, active-directory, group-policy

I'm working to build out an active directory deployment for my network, but when I join one of my test computers to the domain it seems that the computer gains some sort of idle timeout for the network connection. It will simply disconnect after 1-2 hours of being idle, the test machine is a VM running in ESXi so when this happens I have to enter into the console through vCenter to get it to reconnect as I can no longer RDP into it which is VERY annoying.

I'm still running defaults for GPO, but the default GPO has no setting set for anything related to network idle timeouts, am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: Check the power settings of the network cards to make sure they are not being turned off to save power.

Comment: @John Thank you, I guess I overlooked the "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power" option in the adapter options. Or maybe it turned back on when I joined it to the domain. 

Either way, can you rewrite your comment as an answer so i can mark it? Thank you!

Comment: I did post an answer - Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I join one of my test computers to the domain it seems that the
> computer gains some sort of idle timeout for the network connection.
> It will simply disconnect after 1-2 hours of being idle

What I normally do in this circumstance is to check the power settings of the network cards to make sure they are not being turned off to save power.

That normally works.